# Discuss that method of moment estimation is inefficient

Tags: self-study, method-of-moments, generalized-moments

Discuss that method of moment estimation is inefficient.

Then model is

Consider the following linear model

$$y_t = x_t' \beta +u_t$$

where $t =1,...,T$ and $x_t = (x_{1t} x_{2t} ... x_{kt})'$ , $ \beta$ is $k \times 1$ vector of unknown coefficients, $y_t$ is an iid disturbance term with the variance $\sigma^2$ and $E(x_tu_t)=0$ for all t.

————————

I derive $var(u_t)\sigma^2=1/T \sum^T\hat{u_t}^2$

And then how can analyze the inconsistency of MOM?

For example, should I compare OLS estimate with MoM estimate?

Comment: Where is my mistake? Why downvote? I can correct it.

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? This question is tagged as time-series. What time series model are you considering?

Comment: This is general question.  But I will add it. Thank you @Eli

Comment: Is this a time series? You tagged this question as a time series. How are the errors at time t related to the errors at earlier times (t-1, t-2,...)?